# Удалить элемент односвязного списка под номером M

Tags: c, односвязный-список

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что нужно удалить элемент односвязного списка под номером M, то есть я ввожу свою переменную М и под этим номером удаляется определенный элемент односвязного списка.

Вот моя структура :

```
struct prog {
char name[80];
unsigned int kol;
double time1;
double time2;

struct prog* next;
};
```

А вот мой код:

```
void zad5(prog* head, int M) {
    prog* Current = head, * Previous = Current;
    int i = 1;
    while (Current) {
        if (i == M) {
            Previous->next = Current->next;
            free(Current);
            Current = Previous->next;

        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            Previous = Current;
            Current = Current->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том что удаляется элемент односвязного списка под номером М и все следующие элементы тоже удаляются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// missing - update head if element 0 is deleted
while (Current) {
    if (i == M) {
        Previous->next = Current->next;
        free(Current);
        break; // !!!
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
        Previous = Current;
        Current = Current->next;
    }
}
```